# Is there anyway from which we can measure the viscosity of honey using a refractometer?

Tags: biochemistry, experimental-design, organic-chemistry, experimental

Is it possible to use a refractometer to measure the viscosity of honey because as we know, a refractometer is used to measure moisture and therefore water influences the viscosity of honey so is there a way that we can use to measure the viscosity of honey that way or using any other method apart from time since time has a high percentage of uncertainty?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, if refractive index and viscosity are both simply functions of moisture content, you should be able to use one to approximate the other using an empirical standard curve. However, based on [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0260877405000208#fd1), it looks like the relationship between moisture content and viscosity at 25C can vary quite a bit between different types of honey, expecially down below ~18% moisture. So I'd be pretty hesitant to rely on refractive index for acurate viscosity measurements unless you first rigerously validate your methodolgy against empirical viscosity measurements.